# Opening a bank account in France

Tags: bank-account, online-banking, travel, france

I just moved in France, and it seems to be vital to have a bank account here. Even to buy a sim card you need one, and of course if you are going to work legally.

I would like to ask you if it is possible to open an online bank account and be compatible with the french system. Or do you have any suggestions about which banks are good (complete functional online interface with English support) and don't have a big monthly fee to maintain the account.

It would be good if that bank supports also travel benefits, cause i am planning to travel a lot. Like no withdraw fee when you use your card abroad to get money.

Last but not least, i heard that some credit cards can provide you some basic health insurance. I would like to know that too.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  I'm afraid shopping questions are off topic - but I think you can edit your question to be more general.  (i.e.  What are some important features I need to find for a French bank account for a new emigrant?) and ask about what should you look for, not which bank you should pick.  Also, your final question is best as its own, new question.

Answer (score 0):

All banks allow online banking.
HSBC is reputed the most international traditional one.

That said, opening a bank account in a 100% online bank would get you to near 0 cost, and is probably the preferred option.

Every online bank is very similar to each other, so I won't make any recommandation here.

Exemples are ing-direct, boursorama, Fortuneo.

I'm afraid none offer english service, and it might be difficult to get in line with a decent english speaker.

All theses banks will likely offer a gold/premier mastercard/visa, so travelling will not be an issue.
The fees should be <2% for foreign currencies (it vary slightly), and <3€ if you use the ATM in none euro ones.

Comment: At least one of those online banks does do business in the US and sobshould have English-language services. I couldn't tell you how to access thise from France; ask the bank.

Comment: Just because a banking conglomerate has a US subsidary which uses the same brand as their french subsidary, doesn't mean that their french subsidary will have english-speaking support available.